# .htaccess redirect to index.php from root of the site

Tags: php, .htaccess

The problem is that I need to be redirected to projects.test.net/rr/index.php if I come to the root of the site which is http://projects.test.net/rr/

Why the first rewrite rule isn't working? I also tried adding

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^projects.pepperit.net/rr/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

But it's not working. The whole file is here:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^projects.test.net/rr/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$http://projects.test.net/rr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Why isn't the index.php set as the standard directory index?

Comment: Thank you, adding "DirectoryIndex index.php" fixed everything.

Comment: Also added as answer, maybe you can mark it as solution :)

Comment: Ofc, done, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common setting in your server can be a lot, but you want to use index.php that you can set using DirectoryIndex

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^projects.test.net/rr/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$http://projects.test.net/rr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding DirectoryIndex fixed the problem.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^projects.test.net/rr/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$http://projects.test.net/rr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```